# Plant/tree name?

Tags: leaves

I bought what was supposed to be breadfruit seeds. Only one seed grew.[image] I don’t believe this is a breadfruit tree based on leaf shape and texture. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I presume you are concerned that the leaves are not cut or lobed as would be the case for the true breadfruit.

Note the description provided by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadfruit#Description where it mentions that the very similar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artocarpus_mariannensis has entire or mostly unlobed leaves. Perhaps you have A. mariannensis.

Comment: Thanks Colin, the leaves aren’t very similar and clearly not Hawaiian canoe tree either

Answer (score 0):

My first impression was  [Scheffelera](https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=sheffelera&fr=tightropetb&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.petpoisonhelpline.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F10%2FFigure-95.9-Umbrella-Plant-Schefflera-actinophylla.jpg#id=1&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.petpoisonhelpline.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F10%2FFigure-95.9-Umbrella-Plant-Schefflera-actinophylla.jpg&action=click)